# function is not working in my code

Tags: javascript

my problem is that `text3` is undefined in my codes in here:

```
t += text2 + "Case #" + i + ":" + "<br>" + text3 + "<br>";
```

but it is here:

```
$('#pass').keyup(function (e) {
    var strong = new RegExp("^(?=.{11,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
    var normal = new RegExp("^(?=.{4,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))).*$", "g");
    if (strong.test($(this).val())) {
        text3 = "strong";
    } else if (normal.test($(this).val())) {
        text3 = "normal";
    } else {
        text3 = "weak";
    }
    return true;
});
```

here is all of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<p><input placeholder="number of tests" type="text" name="numbers" id="x"/></p>
<div id="passdiv"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#x').keyup(function (e) {

        var i;
        var text2 = '';
        var t = "";
        var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
        for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            text2 = '<p><input placeholder="test NO. ' + i + '" type="password" id="pass" /></p>';
            t += text2 + "Case #" + i + ":" + "<br>" + text3 + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("passdiv").innerHTML = t;

        return true;
    });

    $('#pass').keyup(function (e) {
        var strong = new RegExp("^(?=.{11,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
        var normal = new RegExp("^(?=.{4,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))).*$", "g");
        if (strong.test($(this).val())) {
            text3 = "strong";
        } else if (normal.test($(this).val())) {
            text3 = "normal";
        } else {
            text3 = "weak";
        }
        return true;
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

what is the problem?
please help

Comment: `for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {` -- doesn't really make sense to me. You realise this means this will only "work" if the value of `x` is an integer, right?

Comment: @stealthyninja yes the first input only work with integer

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `$('#x').keyup()` is being called before `$('#pass').keyup()`

Comment: I've changed it but the problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

<del>Your call `$('#x').keyup(function (e) {` is creating the first event listener so on keyup you will always endup with `text3 is undefined` because the `$('#pass').keyup(function (e) {` will be triggered always later.</del>

**EDIT:**

Your second keyup handler will never work because it will grab the `#pass` element only once (during document parse). You need to create some defered listener to fix it.
// Anyway this won't fix your `text3 is undefined` problem.

What you need to do is define it first before the two `.keyup` handlers.

**NOTE:**

But please avoid setting global variables anyway ;)
Put everything into a closure or something.

Last but not least **DO NOT** create many elements with the same ID this is a major bug.

Comment: The functions are called in the order that the user types in the fields, not the order that they're defined.

Comment: Sorry my bad, but how do you want to have something inside your `text3` variable when you have never introduced it?

Answer (score 0):

Look, even after fixing the code to get it to work it makes very little sense. Using roryok's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsuy4t27/), it'll only work if the value you're entering is a number and doing so just spawns the paragraph elements for the number you entered. You can enter as many numbers as you'd like (before your browser crashes), it'll always return as "weak".

If it's a simple password strength meter you're after, unless you can explain the logic you're trying to achieve more by forcing it to stick to numbers, I'd dump most of the JavaScript code and reduce it to

```
$('#x').keyup(function (e) {
    document.getElementById("passdiv").innerHTML = strength($(this).val());

    return true;
});

function strength(val) {    
    var strong = new RegExp("^(?=.{11,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
    var normal = new RegExp("^(?=.{4,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))).*$", "g");
    if (strong.test(val)) {
        t = "strong";
    } else if (normal.test(val)) {
        t = "normal";
    } else {
        t = "weak";
    }
    return t;
}
```

This will then validate the whole input each time you enter a character, which the user can then submit once it's "strong".

Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xqooj482/

Answer (score -1):

`text3` is not set as a variable in your code, therefore it's always going to be undefined. You need to set it before your two functions.

Note: I also put things inside a jQuery ready function.

For some reason I'm being downvoted, but I tested this and it works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<p><input placeholder="number of tests" type="text" name="numbers" id="x"/></p>
<div id="passdiv"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    // set text3 in here first
    var text3 = "";

    $('#x').keyup(function (e) {

        var i;
        var text2 = '';
        var t = "";
        var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
        for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
            text2 = '<p><input placeholder="test NO. ' + i + '" type="password" id="pass" /></p>';
            t += text2 + "Case #" + i + ":" + "<br>" + text3 + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("passdiv").innerHTML = t;

        return true;
    });

    $('#pass').keyup(function (e) {
        var strong = new RegExp("^(?=.{11,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
        var normal = new RegExp("^(?=.{4,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\W))|((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W))).*$", "g");
        if (strong.test($(this).val())) {
            text3 = "strong";
        } else if (normal.test($(this).val())) {
            text3 = "normal";
        } else {
            text3 = "weak";
        }
        return true;
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also here's a fiddle of it working
http://jsfiddle.net/gsuy4t27/

Comment: what am I missing? Why are people downvoting me?

Comment: Because you're wrong. The variable is set in the `$("#pass").keyup()` handler.

Comment: "it's always going to be undefined" - not true. welcome to the ugly world of JS global variables.

Comment: why don't you read the other answers? isn't that the first step when you receive a downvote? there's an opportunity to learn here.

Comment: @roryok Your code is a correct fix, but your explanation is misleading.

Comment: it's a bit of a stetch calling the masking of the problem (replacing undefined variable with an empty string) a correct fix...

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the polite explanation. More than some can give.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Good point. A better solution would be for the `#x` handler to do `if(test3)` and display the strength if it's set, or display a message saying that you need to enter a password first.